# Difference between calcination and pyrolysis

Tags: terminology, heat, materials, pyrolysis

What is the difference between calcination and pyrolysis?

I understand they both involve heat treatment but each under a different type of atmosphere, which leads to some sort of reduction reaction? What are the differences in underlying mechanisms?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcination,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrolysis, or other info on internet?

Comment: Yes but i was hoping to find out more about the chemical mechanisms at play

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially calcination is decomposition at high temperature with inorganic reactants such as calcium carbonate in making cement.
$$\ce{CaCO3 ->[\Delta ] CaO + CO2}$$
Pyrolysis is decomposition or oxidation at high temperatures of organic materials such as cellulose in making charcoal.
$$\ce{(C6H12O6)_{n} ->[\Delta] C7H4O + C_{x}H_{y} + H2O}$$
where $\ce{ C_{x}H_{y}}$ is volatilized byproducts.