# Difference between calcination, roasting and pyrolysis

Tags: terminology, metallurgy, extraction, alloy, pyrolysis

Hie everyone. I have been going through pyrometallurgical processes for recycling lithium-ion batteries and l have been coming across these terms; calcination, pyrolysis and roasting which l need assistance to be able to differentiate them as there is no notable difference when it comes to recycling **lithium-ion batteries**.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39281/30836

Comment: Thanks but l was hoping to get a clear differentiation, maybe the chemical mechanisms at play because when using these techniques sometimes the process conditions are all the same but one journal would choose to call it pyrolysis, roasting or calcination. The material in the battery is Lithium cobalt oxide (LiCoO2). Like l had said the distinction when you are doing extractive metallurgy of ores is clear but for recycling its not.....